# How do groupby with part of column name, dcast and revalue at the same time in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following `dataframe`

```
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd
  df = pd.DataFrame({'x_d_a_b_1to3': [np.NaN, 'yes', 'yes', 'no'],
                   'x_d_a_b_lessthanhalf': ['no', 'no', 'no', np.NaN],
                   'y_k_d_e_lessthanhalf': ['no', 'yes', 'no', np.NaN],
                   'y_k_d_e_1to3': ['yes', 'no', 'no', np.NaN],
                   'id': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

I would like to create two new columns `x_d_a_b_all` and `y_k_d_e_all`, which will have values, either 0, 0.5, 2 or `NaN` depending on the answers in the respective columns.

So for the new column `x_d_a_b_all` the columns `x_d_a_b_1to3` and `x_d_a_b_lessthanhalf` should be taken into account and

for new column `y_k_d_e_all` the columns `y_k_d_e_lessthanhalf` and `y_k_d_e_1to3` should be taken into account.

My final df should look like this

```
df_f = pd.DataFrame({'x_d_a_b_all': [0, 2, 2, 0],          
                       'y_k_d_e_all': [2, 0.5, 0, np.NaN],              
                       'id': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

**Explanation of values on `df_f`:**

So the `id` `1` has `0` for the column `x_d_a_b_all` because has `NaN` and `no` to the respective columns and `2` for the `y_k_d_e_all` column because he has a `no` for `y_k_d_e_lessthanhalf` column but a `yes` for `y_k_d_e_1to3`.

Relatively the `id` `4` has `NaN` for the `y_k_d_e_all` column, because he has `NaN` for both  `y_k_d_e_lessthanhalf` and `y_k_d_e_1to3` and

`id` `2` has `0.5` for the `y_k_d_e_all` because he has `yes` for `y_k_d_e_lessthanhalf` and `no` for `y_k_d_e_1to3`

**To put it in different words**: each id should have the last part of string as value for every column, if the answer is `yes`, `0` if the answer is `no` and the aggregate by the "first 4 parts" of the column name

I am looking for a generic solution, which would work for many columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution, with a not so pythonic way

```
  cols_to_dcast = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('x_d_a_b_|y_k_d_e_')]
    cols_to_dcast_aggregate = list(set(['_'.join(x.split('_', 4)[0:4]) for x in cols_to_dcast]))

    revalue_dict = {'lessthanhalf': 0.5, '1to3': 2, 0:0}

    for col in cols_to_dcast:
        df[col] = np.where(df[col] == 'yes', col.split('_', 5)[-1],
                            np.where(df[col] == 'no', 0, df[col]))
        df[col] = df[col].map(revalue_dict)

    for col in cols_to_dcast_aggregate:
        df[col + '_all'] = df.loc[:, df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(col)]].max(axis=1)

    df = df.drop(columns=cols_to_dcast)
```

A more pythonic answer will be accepted of course :)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand your logic for the output, could you please expand the explanation for each case?

Essentially, you are defining a 2 variable function that returns one value.

This is applied to each row.

I modified your input like this

```
df = df.replace(to_replace={'yes':1,'no':0}).set_index('id')
```

just to have a consistent np.float datafame for easy calculation ( 'yes' is 1 and 'no' is 0). Moreover, using your id as index is easier.

I cannot answer exactly your question, you should define what your function should do for each input something like:

```
logic_x(Nan,0) = 0
logic_x(1,0) = 2
```

and so on. In python words, you want to do is define a function

```
# accept a Series == row in df
def logic_x(x):
    # x_d_a_b_all the : uses x_d_a_b_1to3  x_d_a_b_lessthanhalf
    if np.isnan(x['x_d_a_b_1to3'] * x['x_d_a_b_lessthanhalf']):
        return 0
    else:
        return 2
```

And apply on the DataFrames rows ( note axis = 1)

```
df['x_d_a_b_all'] = df.apply(logic_x, axis=1)
df[['x_d_a_b_1to3','x_d_a_b_lessthanhalf','x_d_a_b_all']]

    x_d_a_b_1to3  x_d_a_b_lessthanhalf  x_d_a_b_all
id                                                 
1            NaN                   0.0            0
2            1.0                   0.0            2
3            1.0                   0.0            2
4            0.0                   NaN            0
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try indexing list this:

The code using two conditional statements to assign the value of the new 'x_d_a_b_all' column which can then be reassigned to a new dataframe if needed. Repeat for the other conditions.

```
df.loc[(df['x_d_a_b_1to3']=='yes') & (df['x_d_a_b_lessthanhalf']=='no'), 'x_d_a_b_all']=2
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for a generic solution